# Prolog Lists and Internal Variables

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

I have a created a predicate that finds a path through a maze, this predicate uses recursion and five parameters, and one of which is a list that returns the path found, everything works fine and the correct path is found but when the list is returned an Prolog internal variable is returned with it.

```
?- maze(X).
X = [start,x,z,s,r,p,q,l,m,w,d,r,l,s,a,t,c,i,d,b,j,k,g|_G2612] .
```

the first node is 'start' and the final node is 'g'.

example code:

```
maze(X) :-
    path(start,colour,g,[],X).

path(From, Colour, To, Visited, [From,To|_]) :-
    connect(From, Colour, To).
path(From, Colour, To, Visited, [From|Route]) :-
    connect(From, Colour, By),
    path(By, Colour2, To, Visited2,Route).
```

I have removed steps within the predicates that doesn't affect the question because this is an assignment where you have to find the path using some other variables.

Comment: If possible, could you add a [mcve] to this post? You can [edit] it into your question. With that, we'll be better able to diagnose the problem.

Comment: It's a little odd to ask what's wrong with your code when you haven't shown any of it, but your results are a symptom of an improperly defined base case more than likely. Somewhere you probably have `[_]` or `[X]` (or some other singleton variable) when it should be `[]`.

Comment: Yep, there it is. `[From, To|_]` should be `[From, To]`. The `_` tail serves no purpose but to leave you with an anonymous variable in the tail of your result.